# How to remove blogger post separator's "text-align:center;"?

Tags: css, blogger, separator, text-align

When we insert a image to blogger post it automatically inserts a separator with 'text-align:center;'. I want to remove it(and set it to left instead of center). But it's hard to remove it manually for every image in every post. Is there a easy way to do this automatically?

I tried .post-body img{float:left;} template CSS. This gets the image to left, but then texts flow to right side of the image instead of under the image. Please help me to do this.

Edit: Below is the normal div that an image would be automatically surrounded when a image is added to a blogger post. Below that is the texts of post.

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"> 
<a href="-----.html"; imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 0em; margin-right: 1em;">
<img alt="" border="0" src="1.bp.blogspot.com/1.JPG"; title="" />
</a></div> 
<br/> 
<span style="font-size: large;">text paragraph texts texts</span><br />
```

Comment: You can try something like `.separator {text-align:left !important;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the <b:skin> or in a separate <style> within the <head> of your template include the following CSS code:

```
.post-body .separator {
   text-align:left !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the rest of your code, if you uploaded something like a js.fiddle that would help! The code below should fix the text alignment with your images, if it doesn't let me know!

```
.post-body img {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;

 }
```

Comment: I had already tried what you said and it doesn't work. As I said image flows to left, but paragraph texts go to right side of image then instead of below to image. Code is like below when a image inserted to blogger. <div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://www.-----.html" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 0em; margin-right: 1em;"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/1.JPG" title="" /></a></div>
<br/>
<span style="font-size: large;">text paragraph texts texts</span><br />

Comment: Will you upload all of your code in a js fiddle so I can see what it looks like! There are a few ways to fix this, I want to give you the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
.post-body .separator a {
    margin: 0!important;
}
```